# How to work out family of functions graphs?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I would like to know manually how to draw the family functions.
I try to find the pictures of the graph, apparently i can find only $x^3$ graph photo below.
what I want to know is how to work out and get this graph?
i have questions like 
 function is $f(x)=x^n$ 
1. $x^1$ 
2. $x^{-1}$ 
3. $x^{-1/4}$ 
4. $x^{1/4}$ 
5. $x^{-2/3}$ 
but I would like to know how to draw the graph by manually solve the functions. 
Hope my question is clear.
Thanks in advance.

eg.  $x^3$

[image: $x^3$]

Answer (score 1):

You can plot functions using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), e.g. [$x^{-2/3}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E%28-2/3%29%20for%20x=0..2,y=0..4). If you want to do it by hand, make a table of some function values in the range of interest, mark the corresponding points in a coordinate system and try to connect them with a smooth curve, using whatever you may now about the function, e.g. zeros, poles, extrema etc.